# React Recoil - use just the setter on the atom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

React Recoil is able to give you access to your atoms as such:

```
  const [inEditMode, setInEditMode] = useRecoilState(seasonInEditMode);
  const seasonsDB = useRecoilValue(seasonsRC);
```

Where the first option works pretty much identical to React state (getter and setter), and the second gives you just the value of the chosen atom (getter).

In my code I use the above but have no use for the getter `inEditMode` - I only use the setter `setInEditMode`.

Is there a method for just declaring the atoms setter without also bringing in the getter? Something like this I guess:

```
const setInEditMode = useRecoilSetter(seasonInEditMode);
```

Comment: why do you want to set a value if you never gonna use the getter

Comment: It is used in another component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be this but would love to get that confirmed:

```
const setInEditMode = useSetRecoilState(seasonInEditMode);
```

Comment: [That is correct.](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/useSetRecoilState).